# mdb-icon not working in Angular when integrated with ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, mdbootstrap

I have successfully integrated MDB Angular Dashboard template in ASP MVC application using this article https://www.mithunvp.com/angular-asp-net-mvc-5-angular-cli-visual-studio-2017/, but now the problem is that the Angular application is now mdb-icon tags are not working anymore

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active"
  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action waves-effect">
  <mdb-icon fas icon="chart-pie" class="mr-3"></mdb-icon>Dashboard
</a>
```

It should show pie char icon but instead showing blank box with errors in console like this

[image: errors]